# NSString lookup in NSSet

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How may I find a certain string (value) in an NSSet?
Must this be done using predicates? If so, how?

```
NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[set addObject:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String %d", 1] autorelease]];
[set addObject:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String %d", 2] autorelease]];
[set addObject:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String %d", 3] autorelease]];
```

Now I want to check if 'String 2' exists in the set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Apple's Developer Site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSSet *sourceSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith 'T'"];
NSSet *filteredSet = [sourceSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
// filteredSet contains (Two, Three)
```

[This article from Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-the-joy-of-nspredicates-and-matching-strings.ars) contains some more information on using predicates. Finally [Apple's BNF guide for predicates](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-CJBDBHCB) contains information on all operations one might need.

Comment: The answer below is more what I hoped for, but thank you for introducing me to NSPredicate!

Answer (score 45):

Strings are equal if their contents are equal, so you can just do:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"String 1", @"String 2", @"String 3", nil];
BOOL containsString2 = [set containsObject:@"String 2"];
```

Using an `NSPredicate` here is overkill, because `NSSet` already has a `-member:` method and a `-containsObject:` method.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is not true that strings are equal (in the sense of ANSI C) if their contents are equal. Strings are equal if their pointer values are equal. However, it is true that you don't need a Predicate, because the `-member:` and `- containsObject:` methods do not compare the objects, but calls the -isEqual: method — which in the case of NSStrings will actually compare the objects's contents, not the objects themselves.

Comment: @KPM except this isn't ANSI C, this is Objective-C, where the `NSString` class has overridden the `-isEqual:` method to do a `strcmp`-like comparison between the two strings. So strictly speaking, two strings are equal if their contents are equal. (I'm not talking about identicalness, which is what you get of two pointers are the same)

Answer (score 2):

might member: work here?

```
member:
Determines whether the set contains an object equal to a given object, and returns that object if it is present.

- (id)member:(id)object
Parameters
object
The object for which to test for membership of the set.
Return Value
If the set contains an object equal to object (as determined by isEqual:) then that object (typically this will be object), otherwise nil.

Discussion
If you override isEqual:, you must also override the hash method for the member: method to work on a set of objects of your class.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
NSSet.h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"String 1", @"String 2", @"String 3", nil];
BOOL containsString2 = [set containsObject:@"String 2"];
```

May or may not work. The compiler may or may not create different objects for the same @"" string, so I would rather do it with MATHCES predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"String 2"];
```